How to stop final rm call when using recursive make
I have a C project that uses gnu make for the build script.
It has the source code split up into modules that are supposed to produce an object archive (.a) file and a header file.
So the directory structure looks kind of like this:
    Makefile
    main.c
    panic/
    |
     \  
      | Makefile
      | panic.c
      | panic.h
      | panic_utils.c
      | ...

Currently it uses recursive invocations of make to build targets. So to build the headers for instance it has the following rules:
    # some rules that define CC CFLAGS AR and ARFLAGS and export them for recursive make.
    include/%.h:    %/header
        cp -v $< $@

    %/header:   %/Makefile
        $(MAKE) -C $$(dirname $@) header

    # followed by some other rules and variables that define the modules and the header files they   produce

Inside the panic module I have a Makefile as follows:
    OBJECTS := $(pathsubst .c,.o,$(wildcard *.c))

    %.o:    %.c %.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

    archive:    $(OBJECTS)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $?

    header: panic.h
        cat $< > $@

I almost have it working, but this is the current behavior when I call for it to make the headers:

user@localhost:~/Programming Projects/project$ make headers
make -C $(dirname panic/header) header
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Programming Projects/project/panic'
cat panic.h > header
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Programming Projects/project/panic'
cp -v panic/header include/panic.h
    'panic/header' -> 'include/panic.h'
rm panic/header`


That last rm call is not specified in any of the Makefiles I wrote, but the gnu documentation on make also doesn't seem to mention it.
It gets applied to target files generated by the recursive make calls. E.g. if I also have modules foo and bar, it will end with rm panic/header foo/header bar/header
In this setup this behavior breaks the dependency checking. (Since it deletes panic/header, include/panic.h doesn't get changed if panic/panic.h gets modified.)
So my question is, how to stop that last rm command?
I have tried the following without any change in behavior:
I tried looking in the gnu docs, but it doesn't seem to mention this behavior.
I tried adding the -r and -R flags (which disable builtin rules and variables respectively) to the recursive make calls.
I tried changing the recursive call to cd $$(dirname $@) && $(MAKE)
I tried emptying any makeflags that get passed on, e.g. export MAKEFLAGS =  and export MFLAGS = 
Any help is very much appreciated!

Turns out I was looking at the wrong part of the documentation.
This behavior has to do with what make does or does not consider to be an intermediate file. I found a solution in this thread: gnu make "Removing intermediate files"
This problem can be solved by adding the pattern to the PRECIOUS target.
E.g.:
.PRECIOUS:      %/header
%/header:       %/Makefile                                                                            
      $(MAKE) -C $$(dirname $@) header

